# Stopping runtime error in C program computing the Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, infinite-loop

I am trying to Write a program that Lets the user to enter two positive integers. Then use the
Euclidean Algorithm with division to compute the Greatest Common Divisor and the Least Common Multiple of the two numbers. Allow the user to repeat this over and over again

This is the code I have so far. I am getting a infinite loop but i cannot figure out why. Please help

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   int posint1, posint2, remainder, Lcm, divisor, dividend;
   int num = 0;

   while(num != -1)
   {
    printf("Enter a positive number to begin Euclidean algorithm ( enter -1 to stop): ");
    scanf("%C", & num );
    if (num != -1)
    {  
printf("Enter the first positive integer ");
scanf("%d", & posint1);
printf("Enter the second positive integer ");
scanf("%d", & posint2);


if (posint1 > posint2)
{
    divisor = posint2;
    dividend = posint1;

    while(posint1 != 0);
    {
        remainder = dividend % divisor;
        dividend = divisor;
        divisor = remainder;         
    }
   printf("The Greatest Common Divisor is %d \n", dividend);
     Lcm = (posint1 * posint2) / dividend;
     printf("The Least Common Multiple is %d \n", Lcm);    
 }

else 

{
 divisor = posint1;
 dividend = posint2;

 while(posint2 != 0);
    {
     remainder = dividend % divisor;
     dividend = divisor;
     divisor = remainder;
    }
 printf("The Greatest Common Divisor is %d \n", dividend);
     Lcm = (posint2 * posint1) / dividend;
     printf("The Least Common Multiple is %d \n", Lcm);  
 }
 }
 }


return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posint1` never changes in this loop, it will loop forever if `posint1` != 0

```
while(posint1 != 0); // <-- remove this semi colon too.
{
    remainder = dividend % divisor;
    dividend = divisor;
    divisor = remainder;         
}
```

Same for this:

```
 while(posint2 != 0); // <-- ;
    {
     remainder = dividend % divisor;
     dividend = divisor;
     divisor = remainder;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it stopped the infinite loop.